# Unable to Generate SSL Certificate using certbot on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, certbot

**Unable to Generate SSL Certificate using certbot on Ubuntu 22.04**

I am trying to request and set up an SSL certificate using certbot for Apache Server running on my [AWS EC2 instance](https://github.com/sndpchatterjee07/AWS-EC2-SETUP/blob/master/README.md) and using an Elastic IP. The instance type is Ubuntu 22.04

`Linux ip-XX-XX-XX-XX 5.19.0-1025-aws #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 24 01:58:15 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

- I ran `apt-get install certbot python3-certbot-apache -y` fine without any issues.
- I then ran `certbot --apache -d XXXXX.ddns.net` which gave me the error below

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Requesting a certificate for sandeepc.ddns.net
Unable to find a virtual host listening on port 80 which is currently needed for Certbot to prove to the CA that you control your domain. Please add a virtual host for port 80.
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/XXXXX.ddns.net.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com
        #ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        #DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ServerName XX.XX.XX.XX
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerAlias XXXXX.ddns.net

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

I have gone through a few posts on Stackoverflow, for example - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59549309/unable-to-find-a-virtual-host-listening-on-port-80-please-add-a-virtual-host) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68641213/issue-with-certbot-to-generate-a-ssl-certificate) but didn't help me resolve the issue.